# Regex pattern for float or integer and space and word

Tags: regex

What could be possible regex pattern for float or integer and space and a word?

Examples:

> str = "12.4 count"

OR

> str = "12 count"

OR

> str = "(12.4 count)"

Comment: If you need help creating a RegEx statement try a utility such as [RegExr](https://regexr.com/), it has references for each token in RegEx and an interactive viewer to show you what your current RegEx string is matching.

Answer (score 1):

To match:

> float or integer and space and a word

This might be an approach:

[`\d*\.?\d+ \w+`](https://regex101.com/r/GDWCal/1)

Explanation

- Match zero or more digits `\d*`
- Match an optional dot `\.?`
- Match one or more digits `\d+`
- A literal space
- Match any word character one or more times `\w+`

Answer (score 0):

This regex would work:

```
([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)? [a-zA-Z]+)
```

- `[0-9]+` will match any integer...
- ...`([.][0-9]+)?` or float...
- ...`[a-zA-Z]+` followed by a space, and a word (assuming that you only want to match characters from the roman alphabet)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
 (\d+(\.\d+)? \w+)
```

```js
var reg = function(str){
  return str.match(/(\d+(\.\d+)? \w+)/g);
}
console.log(reg("12.4 count"));
console.log(reg("12 count"));
console.log(reg("(12.4 count)"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var re = /(\d+(\.\d+)?)\s(\w+)/;

var strs = [
"12.4 count",
"12 count",
"(12.4 count)"
]

strs.forEach(
  (str) => {
    var res = re.exec(str);
    console.log('Full Match', res[0]);
    console.log('Number', res[1]);
    console.log('Word', res[3]);
  }
);
```

This one will give you the the values but only find then once per string.

```js
var re = /(\d+(\.\d+)?)\s(\w+)/g; // Do a global search, more than once per string

var strs = [
"12.4 count. 43.23 mountains.  134 fish.",
"12 count",
"(12.4 count)"
]

strs.forEach(
  (str) => {
    while(true) {
      var res = re.exec(str);
      if (res === null) {
        break;
      }
      console.log('Full Match:', res[0]);
      console.log('Number:', res[1]);
      console.log('Word:', res[3]);
    }
  }
);
```

This one will find every match within a string even if there are multiple matches.

```
/(\d+(\.\d+)?)\s(\w+)/
```

> \d+ = One or more digit
>
> (.\d+)? = Match a . and then one or more digits and the whole thing zero or one times.
>
> \s = Whitespace
>
> \w+ = One ore more Alpha Numeric
>
> The parenthesis are used to create groups so you can pull out the individual sections if you want them